# css image grid layout

Tags: css, tailwind-css

[image]

trying to get this image layout but the second image is just sitting on the first row next to image one, how can i get it to move to the second row?

```
        <div className="grid grid-rows-2 grid-cols-4 gap-5">

            <div className="col-span-1 row-span-1">
                <img className="" src="/assets/product-xx99-mark-two-headphones/desktop/image-gallery-3.jpg"></img>
            </div>

            <div className="col-span-1 row-span-1">
                <img className="" src="/assets/product-xx99-mark-two-headphones/desktop/image-gallery-3.jpg"></img>
            </div>

            <div className="col-span-2 row-span-2">
                <img  src="/assets/product-xx99-mark-two-headphones/desktop/image-gallery-3.jpg"></img>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Here is a working example:

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15rem;
}

.img {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Tailwind styles */

.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.grid-rows-2 {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.grid-cols-4 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.gap-5 {
  gap: 5px;
}

.col-span-1 {
  grid-column: span 1 / span 1;
}

.col-span-2 {
  grid-column: span 2 / span 2;
}

.row-span-1 {
  grid-row: span 1 / span 1;
}

.row-span-2 {
  grid-row: span 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid grid-rows-2 grid-cols-4 gap-5">

    <div class="col-span-1 row-span-1">
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-span-1 row-span-1">
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-span-2 row-span-2">
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your html is invalid. There is no such thing as a closing </img>. Remove those

Answer (score 0):

CSS grids are populated from the top left to the right and then down, so first of all you need to rearrange the order of the HTML so that the large element is in the middle of the three.

Next, the number of columns in your grid is incorrect. You've set the grid to have 4 columns but the small cell is 1 column wide and the large cell is 2 columns wide, which only make 3 columns. You just need to update the grid to have 3 columns instead of 4. Alternatively, you could increase the width of the large cell to 3 columns and keep the grid at 4 columns, but I believe 1:2 looks like the right ratio from your sample image.

Here's an example:

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15rem;
}

.img {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Tailwind styles */

.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.grid-rows-2 {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.grid-cols-3 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.gap-5 {
  gap: 5px;
}

.col-span-1 {
  grid-column: span 1 / span 1;
}

.col-span-2 {
  grid-column: span 2 / span 2;
}

.row-span-1 {
  grid-row: span 1 / span 1;
}

.row-span-2 {
  grid-row: span 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid grid-rows-2 grid-cols-3 gap-5">

    <div class="col-span-1 row-span-1">
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-span-2 row-span-2">
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-span-1 row-span-1">
        <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```